# Flicker on hover of element while trying to shrink it's size on the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$myPseudoEl.on({
    mouseenter: function (e) {
            $(this).animate({
                'width': '50%'
            }, 50);
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
          $(this).animate({
              'width': '70%'
          }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5pwL9jL/) to see it in action. To reproduce it just make sure you enter your cursor inside the element from sideways i.e. from right and left. I know why it is happening, just wanted an elegant solution to it.

Comment: Its because u dont have same width to both the elements. Once mouse enters, element resizes to 50% which causing mouseleave event to trigger

Comment: You want to prevent the flicker?

Comment: @VickyGonsalves I know the reason behind it but needed one solution for it.

Comment: @kpucha Yup, I want to prevent it.

Comment: @Suraj I added an answer with the changes to prevent the flicker.

Answer (score 2):

I would wrap it within a wrapper element:

```js
 var $el = $('#wrapper')
 var $wrapper = $el.find('.handle-content');

 var changeContent = function(content) {
   $wrapper.fadeOut(50, function() {
     $wrapper.html('<span class="handle-content">' + content + '</span>').fadeIn(50);
   });
 };

 var labelChanger = function(off, on) {
   $el.off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
   $el.on({
     mouseenter: function(e) {
       changeContent(on);
       $(this).find('.book-button-handle').animate({
         'width': '50%',
         'height': '15px',
         'color': 'white',
         'background-color': 'black'
       }, 50);
       $('.log').append('<li>enter</li>');
     },
     mouseleave: function(e) {
       changeContent(off);
       $(this).find('.book-button-handle').animate({
         'width': '100%',
         'height': '15px',
         'color': 'black',
         'background-color': 'white'
       }, 50);
       $('.log').append('<li>leave</li>');
     }
   });
 };


 labelChanger("+", "more options");
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
  width: 70%;
  height: 15px;
  background: yellow;
}
.book-button-handle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 15px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div class="book-button-handle">
    <span class="handle-content"> + </span>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="log">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this still flickers while moving your cursor slowly from below.

Comment: this is just an idea nothing else you can see a little gap in there you can set a height.

Comment: Your idea behind it does solve the problem for sure.

Comment: But I wanted a solution by keeping the HTML structure the same. You could play with css or js to derive the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var $el = $('.book-button-handle')
var $wrapper = $el.find('.handle-content');
var enter = false;
var exit = false;

var changeContent = function (content) {
    $wrapper.fadeOut(50, function () {
        $wrapper.html('<span class="handle-content">' + content + '</span>').fadeIn(50);
    });
};

var labelChanger = function (off, on) {
    $el.off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
    $el.on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
          if (!$(this).is(':animated') && !enter){
           changeContent(on);
            $(this).animate({
              'width': '50%',
              'height': '15px',
              'color': 'white',
              'background-color': 'black'
            }, 50);
            $('.log').append('<li>enter</li>');
            enter=true;
            exit=false;
          } 
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
         if (!$(this).is(':animated') && !exit){
            changeContent(off);
            $(this).animate({
              'width': '70%',
              'height': '15px',
              'color': 'black',
              'background-color': 'white'
            }, 50);
            $('.log').append('<li>leave</li>');
            enter=false;
            exit=true;
          }
        }
    });
};


labelChanger("+","more options");
```

```css
.book-button-handle {
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 15px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    font-size: 10pt;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book-button-handle"> <span class="handle-content"> + </span>

</div>
<ul class="log">
</ul>
```

- I added `if (!$(this).is(':animated'))` to prevent the triggering of
  the event while it is under the previous animation.
- I added `if (exit)` & `if (enter)` to prevent triggerint two times
  the same event on enter/leave the element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your solution when I move cursor from sideways it does shrink but when I move out of it doesn't expands back. For that I need to move in my cursor inside the shrink-ed element and than move out.

Comment: If you need to trigger the event when you leave the previous "big space" you should use the answer of @Jai